# How I Could Fix "Invalid attempt to call MetaData when reader is closed"

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I want to make a search system that when i press the button, my textbox and combobox would auto fill with data from database. and at the same time, while the combobox changed, it will be get the specific data that related from the combobox to fill at my textbox2.
sqlconn is SqlConnesction
sqldr is SqlDataRead
textbox1 is the place that i used for auto id
combobox1 for data relation to textbox2
combobox2 for data relation to textbox3
textbox4 for search bar
combobox3 for search category
koneksi.connect is my module to call connect, i use it to connect my form to database

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        koneksi.connect()
        strsql = "SELECT disease_name FROM tb_disease where id_disease='" & ComboBox1.SelectedItem & "'"
        sqlcmd = New SqlCommand(strsql, sqlconn)
        sqldr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader
        sqldr.Read()
        If sqldr.HasRows Then
            TextBox3.Text = sqldr.Item("disease_name")
        End If
        sqldr.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged
        koneksi.connect()
        strsql = "SELECT symptom_name FROM tb_gejala where id_symptom='" & ComboBox2.SelectedItem & "'"
        sqlcmd = New SqlCommand(strsql, sqlconn)
        sqldr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader
        TextBox5.Text = ""
        If sqldr.HasRows Then
            TextBox5.Text = sqldr.Item("symptom_name")
        End If
        sqldr.Close()
    End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If ComboBox3.Text = "Search Category:" Then
            MsgBox("Choose The Search Method First")
        ElseIf ComboBox3.Text = "ID RULE" Then
            sqlcmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tb_rule WHERE id_rule Like '%" & TextBox2.Text & "%'", sqlconn)
            sqldr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader()
            sqldr.Read()
            If sqldr.HasRows Then
                TextBox1.Text = sqldr.Item("id_rule")
                ComboBox1.Text = sqldr.Item("id_disease")
\\the metadata error is under here
                ComboBox2.Text = sqldr.Item("id_symptom")
//the metadata error is up here
            Else
                MsgBox("No Data Match To The Following ID")
            End If
            sqldr.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
```

The way that i ever tired is to remove one of the "Combobox index selected",any of them. but one of them wont fill the textbox2 or textbox3
the second way i ever tried is to remove

```
        If ComboBox3.Text = "Search Category:" Then
            MsgBox("Choose The Search Method First")
        ElseIf ComboBox3.Text = "ID RULE" Then
            sqlcmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tb_rule WHERE id_rule Like '%" & TextBox2.Text & "%'", sqlconn)
            sqldr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader()
            sqldr.Read()
            If sqldr.HasRows Then
                TextBox1.Text = sqldr.Item("id_rule")
                ComboBox1.Text = sqldr.Item("id_disease")
                ComboBox2.Text = sqldr.Item("id_symptom")
            Else
```

to this

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If ComboBox3.Text = "Search Category:" Then
            MsgBox("Choose The Search Method First")
        ElseIf ComboBox3.Text = "ID RULE" Then
            sqlcmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tb_rule WHERE id_rule Like '%" & TextBox2.Text & "%'", sqlconn)
            sqldr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader()
            sqldr.Read()
            If sqldr.HasRows Then
                TextBox1.Text = sqldr.Item("id_rule")
                ComboBox1.Text = sqldr.Item("id_disease")
            Else
```

but one of the combobox would empty.
Both of the solution isn't work.
anything that related to IndexChange is the troublemaker, one called, the other index changed would error, no matter which one i call first.

Sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: 1) You need to call `.Dispose()` on the SqlConnection each time you have finished using it. 2) You should name each column that you want returned instead of using `*`. 3) It would be better to use SQL parameters to pass the values instead of concatenating them into the query string.

Comment: 4) Use `sqldr.HasRows` before trying to read data.

Comment: Even better than calling Dispose().  Wrap the readers with Using blocks.  Also wondering about koneksi.connect() which some of your methods are calling, others aren't.  Is this some sort of global db connection?

Comment: Im sorry for not explaining what is it koneksi.connect(), it is a module, so the module name is "koneksi" and the sub name is connect that i use that to connect my all my form to my database